# Searching for a solution of high load access logging for PHP

Tags: php, performance, nosql, rdbms

I'm searching for a high accessing logging solution.
My "table" has this structure:

```
|   ID    |   Hits   |     LastUsed
______________________________________
|  XYNAME | 34566534 | LastUsedTimeHere
| XYNAMEX | 47845534 | LastUsedTimeHere
| XYNAMEY |  956744  | LastUsedTimeHere
```

I think a often used database system like a Relational Database Management System isn't the right choise here, do you agree?

The single file has a access (about 100.000-400.000 per day) and I need to log each visit with a up-count on the `Hits` and a update on `LastUsed` with the actual time where the `ID` is like some unique string I specify. I read this data real rarely.

(I just have a single server where already other sites run (with PHP & MySQL) and I don't have any income/ads from/at these sites (and I'm a student). So it should be also a solution which is memory/CPU saving. I want to use the solution within PHP.)

I already thought about CouchDB or MongoDB. Have you any experience and could recommend me something/a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to save the individual downloads as separate records, MySQL will handle the load nicely.